Guitar maintenance - Specific questions on applying lemon oil
I have gone thru a similar question here - how does one use or apply lemon oil to a classical guitar?
However I feel it does not specifically address following situations or queries that I have.

Some amazon shopping site reviews mention that lemon oil should be applied on rosewood fretboard only.   I would like to know if it's correct if so what is the rationale behind it
At present my Samick electric guitar (More than 15 years old) has rosewood fretboard, however I have never applied any such moisturizing liquid ever on its fretboard, I live in a region which is dry (very less humidity) and average ambient temperatures are between 20 to 30 Deg Celsius. Will it be a good idea to apply it now?
Does a moisturized fretboard results into any kind of improvements in tone or any difference in the playability of the instrument?


This question is similar to: how does one use or apply lemon oil to a classical guitar?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ojs - Thanks for pointing me to a similar question. While it has very good info, please check my edits to this question. I do not know if I am needed to submit any feedback, however I have resubmitted the edited question.

Oil and water do not mix, and oil is not water, nor is oil a solution of water. I mention that to clarify that using oil on an unfinished fingerboard has nothing to do with "moisture" or "moisturizing" in the sense of adding water content to the fretboard.
Fingerboard oil (not necessarily lemon oil), is a type of protective finish for your fingerboard. Maple fingerboards are finished with either a satin or glossy coating, similar to what might be on the back of a guitar neck. Rosewood and ebony fingerboards have an oil finish. Oil finishes do not last very long, so they have to be re-applied periodically.
This comprehensive article details how wood is affected by sunlight and moisture and also details how different kinds of finishes extend the life of wood products. Regarding oil finishes, the article says this:

Oils. A number of oils (linseed, tung, oiticica) and modified oils have traditionally been used as penetrating wood finishes. These oils do not leave a film, and they do not last longer than 1–1.5 years because of their low resistance to UV light and water. Therefore, penetrating oils find limited use as outdoor finishes, but they are widely used as interior furniture finishes.

I'm not aware of oiling a fretboard having any noticeable effect on tone.
Oiling a fretboard extends the life of the fretboard, does provide a slightly acidic fluid that can aid in the removal of grime, and helps keep the fretboard surface comfortable and smooth.
Note that the moisture content (water, not oil) of an open wood fretboard can change and the wood can swell or shrink if this happens. If you are wondering if your fretboard might have lost water content, then run your hand along it. If the frets are sticking out on the sides and scrape your hand lightly, then your fretboard might have dried out and shrunk a bit. In this case you can oil your fretboard to prevent further loss of moisture and have the edges of the frets filed down, or you can try to spend some time (weeks to months) with a humidifier to see if you can wet your fingerboard again before applying an oil finish.

Now, also if I were petty I’d dv this answer as it for one thing does not really answer the question, and for another thing “you can oil your fretboard to prevent further loss of moisture” is simply not correct. Oil will offer limited protection against water, but is open to diffusion.

@Lazy I don’t mind if you dv. It would make a lot of sense since we have a fundamental disagreement about how wood, oil finishes, and humidity work and interact.

No, because I’m not a prick dv’ing answers due to small parts not really relevant to the total answer, unlike other here. You know sometimes I’m so done with the dynamics of this community. An yes, you are allowed to fundamentally disagree on measurable physical properties. It’s just not a great idea.

I mean, I’m seriously trying to help here, trying to maybe address the issues you guys have with my answer, and instead of addressing this you guys just argue against position I did state. This the exact opposite of constructive feedback. I’m sometime so done with this!

@Lazy If you want constructive feedback then I’d say start reading up on what prominent guitar manufacturers recommend, what studies have been done on how wood behaves in home environments, how oil finishes work, etc. Either you’ll find objective information that supports your answer or you’ll learn new things that you didn’t already know, so it’s a benefit to you no matter how it plays out. BTW if the thing about dving because of “small parts not related to the overall answer” is meant to suggest that’s what I did, then I’d like to clarify that I disagree with the majority of your answer.

Okay, this is a sensitive topic. My stance on this is: Do not use lemon oil on any serious instrument. Like, really! A little bit will at the very best not hurt.
If you really wish to oil your fretboard (which is not even reasonable on all types of wood) do use a proper fingerboard oil, made of turpentine oil and linseed oil. These will cure over time and form a protective layer. So called “lemon oil” is really just white oil, which will not cure, but simply sit in the wood until it evaporates. This will make the wood look more intense, and maybe help to clean off some stuff from the board.
If you look at the material data sheet of say dunlop you will find that the intended use is cleaning and improving the optics. And that’s it. And while cleaning might be reason to do it — just clean your hands before playing and wipe the instrument after playing. If after very long time of careful use the surface is dirty you might use it. On most other instruments other things are used for cleaning fingerboards though (such as spiritus).
Now, let’s ask: Does a fretboard need moistening? No, it doesn’t. Wood does not simply dry out. Both the and the air wood contain moisture, and that moisture can go both ways. The Wood for instrument building is dried carefully over many years to a specific moisture level where this should be at an equilibrium at a normal humidity. Randomly making it wet will act against this and cause danger for warping and cracking in the first place. If the wood dries out over time it simply means that it wasn’t dry enough in the first place, a thing you’ll find especially with cheap instruments. And if you are living in a place that is so dry that your instrument suffers the first thing that would suffer would be the top (and it can cause deformation of the neck). So in that case you’ll really need to keep in instrument at controlled humidity in the first place (e.g. a case with a damp sponge inside). It is a thing that is quite common with most serious instruments, and many cases even come with holders for such things.
To address your questions:

I think the main reason is that rosewood fretboards just have a more open grain and thus get dirty easier. Maple and especially ebony are much less open and smoother, so they will not get dirty as easy. Also rosewood is naturally oily, and as the oils on the surface evaporate the look will deteriorate. Thus in some sense replenishing the oil on the surface would make sense.
Doesn’t this rather prove to you that you do not really need to do this? Rather, if you live in a dry area, check humidity and if necessary use a case humidifier (optimal humidity should be around 40%-60%).
If oil were to penetrate into the wood it would deteriorate the sound quality (even if the fretboard is not the main influence to the sound, especially on electric). But as the oil will not really penetrate into the wood in the first place — there should not be much of a difference. For playability — well, the oil will get the surface oily, which can affect playability to a slight extent by feeling a bit slicker. On the other hand it might raise the grain a bit, making the surface rougher.


“Does a fretboard need moistening? No, it doesn’t. Wood for instrument building is dried carefully over many year, so why would you want to make it wet?” This isn’t how open wood works, especially not tonewoods. If a piece of wood is not completely sealed by a finish on all surfaces, then it will absorb moisture from the air and surrender moisture to the air depending on whether the relative humidity is higher or lower than the evaporation point for the wood. Unfinished wooden fingerboards and kitchen cutting boards and other surfaces have to be oiled to keep their open wood surface and feel.

@ToddWilcox Yes, a difference of diffusion pressure will lead to a change of humidity. But that is exactly the point. The wood is carefully dried to a point were there is neither massive drying not dampening in normal environments. And as I said, if you do happen do be in an challenging environment the way to go would be to control humidity in the case. Just consider this: Instruments have lots of unfinished wood on the insides. So why do you not go around and apply white oil to the insides of your instrument?

I apply two/way humidity control systems to the insides of acoustic instruments just like musicians have for decades, and I also use two-humidity control in my electric guitar and bass cases specifically to keep the fret boards in a ideal environment. The reasons why we don’t oil insides of acoustics is not because they are cured but because it would be difficult, it would throw off the resonances of the woods by changing the density, and we don’t run our fingers over those surfaces so there’s no benefit to oiling them.

Acoustic guitar manufacturers and guitar techs recommend humidity control for solid wood acoustic guitars and players of strings instruments like violin and cello have to use humidity control also. Even grenadilla such as used in clarinets and oboes can get dried and crack if not properly cared for. Curing wood does not make that wood impervious to moisture content changes. Open wood takes in and emits moisture, and it can change in geometry in the process enough to crack and damage the instrument.

For example, Taylor guitars: https://www.taylorguitars.com/support/maintenance/symptoms-wet-guitar

Sadowsky guitars on oiling unfinished fingerboards: https://sadowsky.com/fingerboard-cleaning-and-oiling-everything-you-could-ever-want-to-know/

Ask any long-time chef who uses open wood cutting boards and they also know that open wood should be oiled and cared for to manage its moisture content.

@ToddWilcox Are seriously just comparing cutting boards and musical instruments? Also you are currently straw-manning so hard ... I never claimed that wrong humidity wouldn’t affect an instrument. I did just say that there is no need to moisten a fretboard by putting stuff onto it. Also that second link you gave explicitly states you should never use lemon oil ... What is suggested there is to use linseed oil (so exactly as I said), which essentially means oil varnishing the fretboard (which will add a layer of protection).

@ToddWilcox Also by the way a finish will not protect against drying out, as varnish is open to diffusion. And it is actually important that this happens, as an unequal change of moisture is much more dangerous. Also I do know why insides of instruments are not oiled. I just made a point that if humidity is a problem for the fretboard it will already be a much bigger problem for the whole instrument.

I’m just explaining my downvote which is based on this answer saying that you don’t have to pay attention to the moisture content of open wood fret boards which is not true. Just because the rest of the instrument is also sensitive to moisture doesn’t mean the fretboard isn’t and you can ignore it without consequences. Wood is wood. Cutting boards can be made of open rosewood, ebony, and other hardwoods and they respond to moisture and oil treatment the exact same way because they are the same wood. Also my ebony gets dirty at the same rate as my rosewood

@ToddWilcox But I’m not saying this? I’m specifically saying that in challenging environments you should use a case with controlled humidity. That’s what I’m saying. You are straw-manning really hard.

@ToddWilcox I’ve expanded on the line in question, I hope this now does not cause misunderstanding. As I’m not a native English speaker this can always be a bit of a challenge...

Side note: I don’t understand what you mean by “straw manning". Regarding "Wood does not simply dry out.", it’s my firm belief and experience that it absolutely does dry out, so we will probably not reach agreement. What’s confusing is it seems like you’re saying wood can dry out if it’s left in a dry environment, which to me is exactly how wood can simply dry out. So why do you say wood doesn’t dry out but it actually does dry out in some circumstances?

@ToddWilcox That is exactly what I call straw-manning, as you seem to argue against a position that says that wood would not dry out no matter what, while my point is that wood used for instrument making is dried to a point where it should not dry out under normal conditions, so you do not need to wet it regularly. And I’m not saying you are doing this out of malice, I’m sure you are just misunderstanding my point, which might be aided by weird phrasing on my part.

I’m starting to think what we consider “normal conditions” are very different. Taylor cures their woods to 45%-55% relative humidity. No home or workplace I’ve spent any significant time in over my whole life has been regularly above 40% relative humidity at best. The woods come from rain forests and I live in a temperate zone, but even worse, there’s always AC in the summer and heat in the winter and both of those lower the indoor relative humidity. My guitars will dry out and crack and my fingerboards will shrink and the frets will scrape my hand if I don’t add humidity constantly.

Actually spruce is from a temperate zone I believe, but not rosewood or ebony.

@ToddWilcox In fact the best spruce for instrument making comes from higher altitudes. But it does not really matter so much where that wood is grown, what matters is the condition under which it is dried. Also again I did never argue that you might be living in a particularly dry environment. What I’m saying is that you should not try to humidify carefully dried wood by buttering stuff onto it. And you are focussing on (at this point probably intentionally) misunderstanding one small part of the explanation. I don’t care anymore. Have a good day.

Sorry, I didn’t realize I misunderstood something. I’m pretty sure I understand and just disagree. You wrote “my point is that wood used for instrument making is dried to a point where it should not dry out under normal conditions”. I’m pretty sure I understand what you wrote there. I contend that your statement there is false.

@ToddWilcox As I said, I do not care about discussing this with you anymore. Maybe I’m expecting too much from a person seriously comparing musical instruments to cutting boards.
